# Distance-metric for SIFT descriptors matching

Tags: object-recognition, sift, histogram, distance-metrics

Will using Cosine-Similarity or Histogram Intersection as distance-metric, for matching SIFT descriptors, help to get better results?

Anybody tried on that ever?

Comment: I haven`t tried Cosine-Similarity or Histogram Intersection yet, but Arandjelovic has proposed to use Hellinger metric instead of L2 and shown that it gives better results. http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2012/Arandjelovic12/arandjelovic12.pdf

Comment: have you tried http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ofirpele/SiftDist/

Comment: I have seen it, but since it cannot be used in kd-tree,  it doesn`t fit me - n^2 matching is too slow. RootSIFT - instead - could be easily used in kd-tree.